# Dashboard layout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I want to create a screen with six image buttons that should equally distribute on all screen.
The images are static..I tried it with gridlayout but unable to consume the whole screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider 3 options:

1. Use `TableLayout` with 3 `TableRow`. In each `TableRow` put 2 `Button`s.
2. Use `RelativeLayout`
3. Use vertical `LinearLayout` and nest 3 horizontal `LinearLayout`s with 2 `Button`s in each LL. Then you have to set `android:layout_weight` to eg. 1 for each `Button`.

In my opinion first and second option is worth for consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Below link is fulfill your requirement.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/android-dashboard-design-pattern.html